# Event flow in AS3 - Shoot a bullet

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

My goal is to shoot a bullet everytime I click on ship. What happens, in fact, is that If I click on it once, the bullet is shot, but if I click on it twice before the first bullet is off the screen, the first bullet literally stops(it does not disappear, only stops) and the second bullet is shot.

```
public var ship:Ship = new Ship();
public var bullet:Bullet = new Bullet();

stage.addChild(ship);


ship.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, shoot);

function shoot(e:MouseEvent):void
{ 

  stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, bulletflies);

}

function bulletflies(e:Event):void
{

  stage.addChild(bullet);
  bullet.y -= 5; 
}
```

Comment: Well, if the bullet stops at the middle of the screen when I shoot another bullet is because I made some mistake.

Comment: With the above code only once instance of a bullet will exist. Since you are saying there can be two bullets on the screen at once I am assuming you have left out the code where you keep creating more bullets?

Answer (score 2):

Set up the bullet as it's own class and have that class iterate the movement on it's own:

```
public class Bullet extends Sprite {
    public function Bullet(ship:Ship) {
        // this assumes that you've also set "Ship" up as it's own class

        this.x = ship.x;
        this.y = ship.y;

        this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, this.enterFrameHandler);
    }

    private function enterFrameHandler(event:Event):void {
        this.y -= 1;
        // destroy this clip when it's outside of the stage - better mem managament
        if(this.y < 0 || this.y > this.stage.stageHeight) {
             this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, this.enterFrameHandler);
             this.parent.removeChild(this);
        }
    }
}
```

In your Ship class, change your shoot function to:

```
function shoot(e:MouseEvent):void {
    this.addChild(new Bullet(this));
}
```

It's good to have the Ship as one class and Bullet as another. This way each object is taking care of **it's self**. Also, if you end up having `EnemyBullet` then you can start using *inheritance* and *polymorphism* (I bet you'll like those once you learn them).

Comment: Very nice except I don't like the idea of each bullet having it's own ENTER_FRAME - should *really* have a step() function for all of your objects and call it on each object in a main for each()

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have only 1 bullet.

You can create an array of bullets, so change

```
public var bullet:Bullet = new Bullet();
```

to

```
public var bullets:Array = [];
```

Then,

```
ship.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, shoot);

function shoot(e:MouseEvent):void
{ 

  var b:Bullet=new Bullet();
  b.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, bulletflies);
  stage.addChild(b);
  bullets.push(b);

}

function bulletflies(e:Event):void
{
  e.currentTarget.y -= 5;
  if(e.currentTarget.y < 0 || e.currentTarget.y > stage.height) {
    stage.removeChild(e.currentTarget);
    bullets.splice(bullets.indexOf(e.currentTarget), 1);
  }
}
```

--EDIT--

In response to your comment

> **I don't like the idea of each bullet having it's own ENTER_FRAME**

Add a line `stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, bulletflies);` under `ship.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, shoot);`

Remove `b.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, bulletflies);`

and change the event handler to this:

```
function bulletflies(e:Event):void
{
  for each(var b:Bullet in bullets) {
    b.y -= 5;
    if(b.y < 0 || b.y > stage.height) {
      stage.removeChild(b);
      //bullets.splice(bullets.indexOf(b), 1);
     }
  }
}
```